# Boot full Android stack from init service

Tags: android, android-source, init

I have placed an Android device in "charger mode": `am.QueueEventTrigger("charger");`, during boot up  "late-init" is not executed.

Then there are some services implemented in: `init.MY_HARDWARE.rc` file: `service my-service-1 /system/bin/modprobe` etc...

These I can trigger with:
`start my-service-1`

Once I have done testing I want to continue with a full system boot up to Android i.e I want to trigger the equivalent of: `am.QueueEventTrigger("late-init")`

Question:

Is it possible to create a service:
`service full-boot XXXXXXX`

That somehow trigger the "late-init" and continues the boot?